# Emptying the innerHTML of an element empties the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have this test program that I wrote just to take confidence with Javascript. For now I am interested only about the client side script, so I don't need PHP, I just wanted to write a script able to read the values of some text fields and to do something with it.

I have defined a class constructor `Person`, able to hold the properties `name`, `surname` and `age`. With a function `getDescription()` able to return the full description of the person. I start with an array of a single element, when the user presses the button I read the text field values, possibly create a `Person` object (if fields are typed correctly), and add the person description using the `innerHTML` property of the element with the id "people". This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> People </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center"> People </h1>
        <p id="input">
            Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            Age <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
            <input type="button" onClick="insert()" value="Insert new Person"/>
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Classe persona:
            function Person(name,surname, age) {
                this.name= name;
                this.surname= surname;
                this.age= age;
            }
            Person.prototype.getDesciption= function () {
                return "Name: " + this.name + " surname: " + this.surname + " age: " + this.age; 
            }

            // Inserimento persona:
            function insert() {
                var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
                var surname= document.getElementById("surname").value;
                var age= document.getElementById("age").value;
                if(name.length > 0 && surname.length>0 && age.length>0)
                {
                    age= parseInt(age);
                    if(isNaN(age))
                    {
                        alert("Incorrect age");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        var person= new Person(name,surname,age);
                        people.push(person);
                        document.getElementById("people").innerHTML="";
                        showPeople();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Do not insert empty fields");
                }
            }

            // Mostra le persone:
            function showPeople() {
                document.write("<p id='people'>");
                for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
                    document.write("<p>");
                    document.write(people[i].getDesciption());
                    document.write("</p>");
                }
                document.write("</p>");
            }

            var people= [ new Person("Mario","Bros",25) ];
            showPeople();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I click on the button, the new person gets added but the buttons disappear. This is before pressing the button:

[image]

And after:

[image]

So why when I set the inner HTML of "people" to an empty string also the other stuff disappear?

Comment: @adam It's generated in `Insert()`. @Ramy, You are adding `people` to the DOM *after* you call `getElementById`. It doesn't exist the first time you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use function `document.write` within function showPeople(), which write HTML content in current document of your whole web page.

You also need to add a new element to your HTML doc with id `people` because it doesn't exist:

```
<div id="people"></div>
```

Please use a string to append what you need and then set the innerHTML of an element.

An updated version of function `showPeople()`:

```
function showPeople(persons) {
    var personDesc = "";
    for(var i=0; i<persons.length; i++) {
        personDesc += "<p>";
        personDesc += people[i].getDesciption();
        personDesc += "</p>";
    }
    document.getElementById('people').innerHTML = personDesc;
}
```

Comment: Or use eg. jQuery's $('#people').val() is you can use jQuery for your target environment.

Answer (score -1):

Also, `<p id="People"> <p> your people </p> </p>` is not valid, you'd better make the outer p's be a div instead.